# Read each line in file and put each line into a string

Tags: c#, asp.net, split, text-files, streamreader

I have a text file that I want to read in and put each line from the file into its own string.
So the file will have 4 lines:

> 2017-01-20
>   05:59:30
>   +353879833382
>   971575 Michael

So in the code I need to read in the file and split up each line and put them into a string i.e the first line will equal to string date, second line will equal to string time etc

Code:

```
public static void ParseTXTFile(string FileName, int CompanyID)
        {
            try
            {
                FileInfo file = new FileInfo(FileName);
                string Date;
                string Time;
                string Phone;
                string JobNo;
                string Name;

                using (CsvReader reader = new CsvReader(new StreamReader(FileName), false))
                {
                    while (reader.ReadNextRecord())
                    {


                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw (ex);
            }
        }
```

How do I read in each line of the file and set it to a string?

Comment: `string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filename);`

Comment: As an aside use `throw;` not `throw ex;` to rethrow else you will lose an accurate stack.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may want to consider using the [`File.ReadAllLines()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines(v=vs.110).aspx) method which will store each line of your file into an array :

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(FileName);
```

You could then access each of your properties by their indices as needed :

```
string Date = lines[0];
string Time = lines[1];
string Phone = lines[2];
string JobNo = lines[3];
string Name = lines[4];
```